# What is a bijection between CDF and characteristic function?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae), it's written that there is a one-to-one correspondance between CDF and characteristic function of a r.v. Could someone give me this bijection ?

Moreover, what does it mean that *"The characteristic function $\varphi _X$ determine uniquely the law of $X$"* ? (written in the [french wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_caract%C3%A9ristique_(probabilit%C3%A9s))). Indeed, by the "bijection" between CDF and characteristic functions, I can imagine that knowing the characteristic function of the r.v. $X$, we can deduce the law of $X$. But what does it mean "uniquely" ? Because a r.v. can't have several law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essential is that - if $\mathcal F$ denotes the collection of all CDF's on $\mathbb R$ - the function $\chi:\mathcal F\to\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}$ prescribed by:$$F\mapsto\phi_F(t):=\int e^{itx}dF(x)$$ is injective. Here the RHS must be read as an element of $\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}$.

So if $\mathcal X$ is defined as the image of the function $\chi$ then automatically the restricted function $\mathcal F\to\mathcal X$ prescribed by $F\mapsto\chi(F)$ is a bijection.